# Django REST Framework- how can I create or update a foreign key object when POSTing parent

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am currently working on an API view, for a Job Planning system.  Each `Job`, has a single `JobPlan` (which has a start and end date) and each `JobPlan`, may have several `JobPlanManagers`, users assigned to manage said `Job`.  User one might be in charge of one month, and User two might overlap User 1, but extend the job by a couple of weeks.  Thus, when User 2 POSTS their new `JobPlanManager` instance, they need to either create a new JobPlan (if no plan yet exists) or update the existing `JobPlan`, to extend the start and end appropriately.  The user's POST data would include their user ID, the Job ID, and a start and end date, something like:

```
{
  "manager": (User ID),
  "job_plan": {
    "id": null,
    "job": {
      "id": (existing Job ID)
    },
    "start": "2018-02-01",
    "end": "2018-02-28"
  }
}
```

Additionally, I would like the return of this POST call to include all fields for JobPlan and Job, nested: e.g.:

```
{
  "id": (created JobPlanManager instance ID)
  "manager": (User ID),
  "job_plan": {
    "id": (New or existing JobPlan ID)
    "job": {
      "id": (Existing Job ID),
      "name": "Existing Job Name"
    }
    "start": "2018-01-02",
    "end": "2018-02-28"
  }
}
```

My models look like:

```
class Job(models.Model)
    name = models.CharField()


class JobPlan(models.Model):
    job = models.ForeignKey(Job, unique=True)
    start = models.DateField()
    end = models.DateField()


class JobPlanManager(models.Model):
    job_plan = models.ForeignKey(JobPlan)
    manager = models.ForeignKey(User)
    is_open = models.Boolean(default=False)
    delta = models.IntegerField()
```

For my serializers, I am doing this in separate calls (e.g.- first create/update a `JobPlan`, then pass the returned id along with the user ID to create my new `JobPlanManager`), and they look like this:

```
class JobSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Job
        fields = ('id', 'name',)
        read_only_fields('id')


class JobPlanSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    job = JobSerializer(many=False)

    class Meta:
        model = JobPlan
        fields = ('id', 'job', 'start', 'end',)
        read_only_fields('id')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        i_job = validated_data.get('job', None)
        start = validated_data.get('start', None)
        end = validated_data.get('end', None)
        if JobPlan.objects.filter(job=i_job).exists():
            jobplan = JobPlan.objects.get(job=i_job)
            jobplan.start = min(jobplan.start, start)
            jobplan.end = max(jobplan.end, end)
            jobplan.save()
        else:
            jobplan = JobPlan.objects.create(job=i_job, start=start, end=end)
        return jobplan

class JobPlanManagerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    job_plan = JobPlanSerializer(many=False)

    class Meta:
        model = JobPlanManager
        fields = ('job_plan', 'manager', 'is_open', 'delta',)
        read_only_fields('id')
```

Does anyone know of a way, that I can do this all in one call (as described above) and get the return described above from said call?

Answer (score 1):

I use this trick to make it work:

```
class JobPlanSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    job = PrimaryKeyRelatedField()

    class Meta:
        ...

    def create(self, validated_data):
        ...

    def to_representation(self, instance):
        ret = super().to_representation(instance)
        ret['job'] = JobSerializer(context=self.context).to_representation(instance.job)
        return ret
```

When posting data just send `"job": (Existing Job ID)`

instead of 
`"job": {"id": (existing Job ID)}`